# Отфильтровать и вернуть коллекцию List С#

Tags: c#, list, linq

Есть список пустых "ответов", и при ответе (Submit) создается новый объект с таким же номером (1, 2, 3 и тд), а в его свойства прописывается ID отвечающего.
Пустые с `listId` `null` я оставляю а не перезаписываю.
Проблема в том, что пустой ответ нужно скрыть со страницы, выводя на экран только то что имеет `ID` юзера (т.е. вновь созданный) и оставшиеся пустые (которые ещё не задублированы)!
Мои решения с `if/else` не помогают т.к. сразу возвращают список удовлетворив лишь одно из условий. В итоге всегда получаю или 1 нужный ответ, или все пустые, или все заполненнные + все пустые.
[image: Так если просто вернуть весь список]

Фактически у ответа имеется 3 основных property:
`Id` (всегда уникальное);
`AnswerListId` (`null` или == `userId`, присваивается при добавлении ответа, едино для всего листа);
`Number` (номера строк что видно на фото, идентичны у всех пользователей)

Вот пример попытки, где у меня не выводятся ненужные `Null`и, но пока я не нажму подтвердить последний вопрос я не вижу ответов. После последнего Submit в списке я всё вижу как надо, и даже могу редактировать ответы.

```
public IEnumerable<AnswersList> GetAllAnswers(string guestId)
{
    var result = _answersLists.Where(x => x.Number > 0);

    foreach (var a in _answersLists)
    {
        var maxRows = _answersLists.Max(x => x.Number);

        for (int i = 1; i <= maxRows; i++)
        {
            if (a.Number >= i && a.AnswersListId != null) // так выводит заполненные после последнего ответа!
                result = _answersLists.Where(b => b.AnswersListId == guestId);

            else result = _answersLists.Where(b => b.AnswersListId == null);
        }
        result = result.OrderBy(g => g.Number).ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните к какому языку относится ваш вопрос.

Comment: Прошу прощения забыл, C#

Comment: Без кода полезность вашего текста околонулевая. У вас есть некий код, вы его не до конца понимаете (иначе бы уже решили своб проблему), но при этом вы пытаетесь своими словами что то описать, чтобы читатели ваш код представили по своему? Это как сарафанное радио, я пойду соседу про ваш вопрос расскажу, он своему знакомому, через пару-тройку итераций от вашего изначального вопроса не останется ничего.

Comment: Добавил один из вариантов, спасибо! Но вижу "тест1-3" только после того как добавляю ответ тест4...

Comment: Я честно пытался рахобраться в вашем коде, и даже вижу ошибку, но не могу найти решение: 1) непонятно, зачем все так сложно, и какова изначальная задача. 2) непонятно, как используется код извне. Нужен [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ошибка у вас с цикле `for`, ответьте себе на вопрос, сколько раз перезапишется `result` сам поверх себя до возврата из метода, в идеале он вообще не должен перезаписываться, вам нужно либо сразу в `return` отправлять результат, либо грамотно прервать цикл.

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь понял вас правильно.
Вот основной метод:

```
public static IEnumerable<AnswersList> GetNonDuplicateAnswers()
{
    var result = _answersLists.Where(al => al.AnswersListId != null).ToList();
    foreach (var list in _answersLists)
    {
        if (!result.Any(al => al.Number == list.Number))
        {
            result.Add(list);
        }
    }

    return result.OrderBy(g => g.Number);
}
```

Если добавить этот код:

```
public class AnswersList
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string AnswersListId { get; set; }
}

public static List<AnswersList> _answersLists { get; set; } = new List<AnswersList>()
{
    new AnswersList() { Number = 1, AnswersListId = null},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 1, AnswersListId = "first"},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 2, AnswersListId = null},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 3, AnswersListId = null},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 3, AnswersListId = "second"},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 4, AnswersListId = null},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 4, AnswersListId = "third"},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 5, AnswersListId = null},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 6, AnswersListId = null},
    new AnswersList() { Number = 6, AnswersListId = "fourth"}
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var list in GetNonDuplicateAnswers())
    {
        var answerId = list.AnswersListId == null ? string.Empty : list.AnswersListId;
        Console.WriteLine($"Number: {list.Number} - AnswersListId: {answerId}");
    }
}
```

Можно получить такой результат:
[image: результат]
(Это не самое оптимальное решение и я уверен, что есть лучше, но, к сожалению, я не могу его увидеть)

Comment: Можно сразу `return result.OrderBy(g => g.Number);`

Comment: Действительно) Спасибо)

Comment: Не могу остановиться :) первые 2 строки можно записать вот так `var result = answersLists.Where(al => al.AnswersListId != null).ToList();`. и вы скобочку потеряли, там где `Any`

Comment: Так гораздо лучше выглядит. Спасибо)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё работает прекрасно, просто вставил Ваш метод и добавил лишь одно условие .Where(al => al.AnswersListId == guestId), т.к. когда новый юзер с другим ID заходит он видел ответы прошлого.